# Printing out each array element

Tags: php

I have an array and I use `print_r` and this what happen:

```
Array
(
    [141] => 1
    [171] => 3
    [156] => 2
    [241] => 1
    [271] => 1
    [256] => 1
    [341] => 1
    [371] => 1
    [356] => 1
    [441] => 1
    [471] => 1
)
```

How can I print out the index [141] and so on?

Comment: You might want to look through the manual. The `foreach` control-structure in particular http://au2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 7):

Use foreach loop to get

```
foreach($your_array as $key=>$value) {
    echo 'index is '.$key.' and value is '.$value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you already know the array index:

```
$arrayIndex = 141;
echo $yourarray[$arrayIndex];
```

or loop through the array like this:

```
foreach ($yourarray as $arrayItem) {
echo $arrayItem;
}
```

or if you need to find out array key/index:

```
foreach ($yourarray as $arrayIndex=>$arrayItem) {
echo $arrayIndex." - ". $arrayItem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the keys of an associative array:

```
echo implode(', ', array_keys(array(141=>'a', 142=>'b')));
// prints: 141, 142
```